# ssh publickey authentication failure: receive packet: type 51. sshd is not accepting publickey auth at all

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, key-authentication

I have read numerous solutions to this problem, but none seem to apply to what I'm seeing. Most focus on directory permissions, but those appear to be correct in this case. TL;DR: Two Centos7 servers with the same home directory; one's `sshd` is not allowing publickey authentication even though it is enabled.

I have two centos7 servers, let's call them `centos-a` and `centos-b`. Home directories are mounted via NFS, so the `.ssh` directories are identical between both (confirmation of this below). I can ssh from `centos-a` to `centos-a`, but not to `centos-b`. I can ssh from `centos-b` to `centos-a` and to `centos-b`.

| ssh-ability | `centos-a` | `centos-b` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `centos-a` | YES | NO |
| `centos-b` | YES | YES |

```
[myuser@centos-a ~]$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 16
drwx------. 1 myuser domain users    0 Jul  6 11:45 .
drwx------. 1 myuser domain users    0 Jul  7 13:44 ..
-rw-------. 1 myuser domain users 1212 Jul  6 12:02 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 myuser domain users 1675 Jul  6 11:45 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser domain users  402 Jul  6 11:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser domain users 1119 Jul  6 17:49 known_hosts

[myuser@centos-a ~]$ md5sum ~/.ssh/*
65b4fdf2d59cee3ae45b8480454453ec  /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
fa3e9fc5a8ff08787ff2ba8f979da24e  /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
dca36ab3ec342423c5eca588f2ad5678  /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
f67bc94bc7a30b9876e3027b24f893d8  /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts

[myuser@centos-a ~]$ ssh centos-a hostname
centos-a

[myuser@centos-a ~]$ ssh centos-b hostname
myuser@centos-b's password:
```

```
[myuser@centos-b ~]$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 16
drwx------. 1 myser domain users    0 Jul  6 11:45 .
drwx------. 1 myser domain users    0 Jul  7 13:44 ..
-rw-------. 1 myser domain users 1212 Jul  6 12:02 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 myser domain users 1675 Jul  6 11:45 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 myser domain users  402 Jul  6 11:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 myser domain users 1119 Jul  6 17:49 known_hosts

[myuser@centos-b ~]$ md5sum ~/.ssh/*
65b4fdf2d59cee3ae45b8480454453ec  /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
fa3e9fc5a8ff08787ff2ba8f979da24e  /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
dca36ab3ec342423c5eca588f2ad5678  /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
f67bc94bc7a30b9876e3027b24f893d8  /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts

[myuser@centos-b ~]$ ssh centos-b hostname
centos-b

[myuser@centos-b ~]$ ssh centos-a hostname
centos-a
```

As shown above, the permissions on the .ssh directory appears to be correct (and, regardless, is identical between both machines).

`ssh -vvv` on the failing ssh shows:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
...
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
...
debug1: Host 'centos-b' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1211402155)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1211402155)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myuser@centos-b's password:
```

Contrast this to what I see going from `centos-b` to `centos-a`, which works:

```
...
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:nAO5pVOzqUQzEUSEBN37WKp6ADs9Sk4rfTRGmk0FHEY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:nAO5pVOzqUQzEUSEBN37WKp6ADs9Sk4rfTRGmk0FHEY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

I've enabled sshd log messages in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarted the service

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel INFO
```

But there are no additional useful messages in either `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/messages`.

*Interestingly* the ssh from `centos-b` to `centos-b` is using gssapi authentication. If I force it to use publickey it fails:

```
[myuser@centos-b ~]$ ssh -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey centos-b hostname
...
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

and I see in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jul  7 13:52:10 centos-b sshd[23266]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.100 port 48064 [preauth]
```

pubkey is enabled:

```
[root@centos-b ssh]# sshd -T | grep -i pub
pubkeyauthentication yes
pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha...
```

The `sshd_config` is a stock Centos7 `sshd_config`, and is identical between `centos-a` and `centos-b` (verified by piping the following command through `md5sum` on both machines

```
[root@centos-b ssh]# grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Any suggestions for what I'm missing?

Comment: `debug3: receive packet: type 51` is a generic `SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE` per `ssh2.h`. What does the `sshd_config` look like on the servers?

Comment: The `sshd_config` is the stock one installed with Centos7; I'll update the question with the contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional googling revealed to me that the issue was with SELinux being enabled on the new systems I've configured. In my case setting this to permissive solves my issue.

```
# getenforce
Enforcing
# setenforce 0
# getenforce
Permissive
```

That might not be the right solution for people who require SELinux in their environment. The permanent change involves updating `/etc/selinux/config`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue will likely have to do with the SELinux contexts on the ID's `.ssh` directory (and maybe more). look to the contexts (in `.ssh`) to have a type of `ssh_home_t`.

This is similar to the SSH user file's required permissions (no `rwx` for group/other). I've not checked but it may be required on both ends (both source and target user's `.ssh` dir needs that same contexts).

This is an example of the "correct" contexts:

```
[account@hostname .ssh]# ls -alZ
drwx------. account account unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .
drwx------. account account unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 ..
-rw-------. account account unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 authorized_keys
-rw-------. account account unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 id_rsa
-rw-------. account account unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--. account account unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 known_hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I just spent 5 hours chasing my tail on this with a newly built Debian 12 server; doing the same things:

- Checking permissions on the .ssh files/folders
- Comparing /etc/ssh/sshd_config files with working hosts
- Comparing `sshd -T` outputs with working hosts
- Comparing outputs of `ssh -vvv root@host 2>ssh.log`
- LOTS of web research

Turns out, and I am still not quite certain why this happened for this particular host - I do this on dozens of vms a month, but when I executed `scp-copy-id root@host`, it installed an alternate public key I use for other purposes rather than what I thought was the default **~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**.

So if you have arrived here and have not yet done so, compare the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the target with the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on the client.

If these are not the same, then you need to remove the incorrect entry from authorized_keys (or just delete the file if there is only one) on the target host and then get explicit:

`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@host`

I have so amended my build procedures and now I will have several large martinis ...